# What is the Taylor series expansion of $f(x) = \sin \pi x$ at $x=1$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have to find the taylor series expansion of f(x) = sin πx at x=1 upto 3 terms [ f'''(x) ] .

I have written a solution which I am not sure if it is correct .

f(x) = sinπx

f'(x) = cosπx . π

f''(x) = -sin πx .π^2

f''' (x) = -π^3 cosπ

f(1) = 0

f''(1) = -π

f'''(1) = π^3

taylor series :
f(x) = 0 -π(x-1) / 1!+ π^3(x-3)/3!

Could you please check if this is the right answer ?

Comment: Here's a [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial :)

Comment: Better way: $\sin (\pi x)=-\sin (\pi (x-1))$. Just use the expansion of sine function.

Comment: you can check your anwser in here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Series%5B%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Asin%28πx%29%2F%2F%5D%2C+%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Ax%2F%2F%5D%2C+%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A1%2F%2F%5D%2C+%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A10%2F%2F%5D%7D%5D

Comment: Make $x=t-1$; simplify the sine and then $t=\frac u \pi$

Answer (score 0):

The formula for Taylor series is given by
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)^n}{n!}$$

where $f^{(n)}(a)$ is the $nth$ derivative of  $f(x)$ evaluated at $ x=a$ . Therefore, to calculate this series you will need to know the value of all of the derivatives of $f(x)$ at $x=a$ .

Now,as you have done,

$f(x) = \sin πx$

$f'(x) =π \cos πx $

$f''(x) = -π^2\sin πx$

$f''' (x) = -π^3 \cos πx$ (you have written it wrong)

So,$f(1) = 0$

$f'(1)=-π$

$f''(1) =0$

$f'''(1) = π^3$

$\therefore $ Taylor series about $x=1$:$$ f(x) = 0 -\frac{π(x-1)} {1!}+0+\frac {π^3(x-1)^3}{3!}$$upto 3 terms.

Note: Actually,$$f^{(0)}(1) =f(1)$$ $$f^{(1)}(1) =f'(1)$$ and so on.

Comment: $f(x)$
 is not *equal* to your final *polynomial*. The remainder $o((x-1)^3)$ *at the end of the same line* is missing. Writing "upto 3 terms" on the next line does not suffice make the equality correct.

Comment: Also, though it is the case here, be careful that a smooth function $f$ is not always [equal to the infinite Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) which you wrote at the beginning of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @geetha290krm and @ClaudeLeibovici, a smarter way is to change of variable and use the wellknown expansion of $\sin$ at $0$:

As $x\to1,$
$$h:=x-1\to0$$ and
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=\sin(\pi(1+h))\\&=-\sin(\pi h)\\&=-\pi h+\frac{(\pi h)^3}6+o(h^3).\end{align}$$